# If - Else If statement in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

```
Else If exist "K:\ICT  project"
    (Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "K:\ICT  project" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing)
Else If exist "F:\ICT  project"
    (Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "F:\ICT  project" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing)
Else If exist "E:\ICT  project"
    (Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "E:\ICT  project" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing)
Else If exist "D:\ICT  project"
    (Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "D:\ICT  project" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing)
Else If exist "C:\ICT  project"
    (Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\ICT  project" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing)
```

What is wrong with the code? And how well the `If` statement is used? please help me.

How can this code be improved?

Comment: No idea what is wrong about the code. What error messages are you getting and/or what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Is there anything wrong?  Do you just mean that you don't like the repetition?  Or does something actually not work?

Comment: How about you start with a clear description of the problem you're experiencing? Including error messages?

Comment: no, it does work

Answer (score 0):

To search for a program on different drives and call it (perhaps with arguments and decent quotes), use a loop over the drives:

```
Option Explicit

Const csPrg = "pipapo"

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sDL, sFSpec, sCmd
For Each sDL In Split("A:\ C:\ K:\ E:\")
    sFSpec = goFS.BuildPath(sDL, csPrg)
    sCmd = Join(Array("%comspec% /c", qq(sFSpec), "/p:arm", qq("one two three"), 4711))
    WScript.Echo sCmd 
    If goFS.FileExists(sFSpec) Then Wscript.Echo "  ==> now run sCmd (and perhaps Exit For)"
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 47922850.vbs
%comspec% /c "A:\pipapo" /p:arm "one two three" 4711
%comspec% /c "C:\pipapo" /p:arm "one two three" 4711
%comspec% /c "K:\pipapo" /p:arm "one two three" 4711
%comspec% /c "E:\pipapo" /p:arm "one two three" 4711
  ==> now run sCmd (and perhaps Exit For)
```

Comment: it does not work , what i meant is how to search at different usb drive  and run the bat file  silently that might exist there . I'm not a programmer , so if you may give me a simple explanation about how can i do that?? Thanks bro